# ember-cli http-mock not returning to my app

Tags: ember.js, model, ember-cli

So I added an http-mock for users that returns just a single user on the get route like so...

```
  usersRouter.get('/:id', function(req, res) {
    res.send({
      "users": {
        "id": 1,
        "pin": 1234,
        "first_name": "John",
        "last_name": "Doe",
        "email": "email@example.com",
        "phone": 8436376960
      }
    });
  });
```

In my model I have this

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  pin: DS.attr('number'),
  first_name: DS.attr('string'),
  last_name: DS.attr('string'),
  email: DS.attr('string'),
  phone: DS.attr('number')
});
```

and in my action when I submit a form I have this to perform the get request

```
return this.store.find('user',id);
```

when I click on the submit button I see in the console a 404 error to the get url like so

```
GET http://localhost:4200/users/1 404 (Not Found)
```

do I need to do anything else to get this mock to work? I didn't see anything about needing an adapter or serializer to get the mock to work

Comment: Shouldn’t the API return a `"user"`, not `"users"`? If that doesn’t work, can you share the rest of your mock configuration?

Comment: I follower convention in the ember-cli documentation which shows using pluralization in http-mocks. But as you can see in the URL it looks like ember is expecting the url to be pluralized. Ultimately I had to generate an application adapter and set the name space to api. I could have also changed the express app to use just '/users' instead of /api/users' but new http-mocks will use the /api format to I thought it best to just use the adapter approach.

Answer (score 3):

I noticed when generating an http-mock in ember-cli the express app code states

```
app.use('/api/users', usersRouter);
```

and ember was just looking at `/users/:id` so I simple generated an application adapter, rest was fine here, and set the namespace like so

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    'namespace': 'api'
});
```

I decided to go with this approach as apposed to removing the api url endpoint from the app.use because future http-mocks will use the api endpoint in their app.use and I thought it best for future generation of http-mocks to just create an adapter.